# DUO 2FA login attempt via Python

Tags: python, authentication

I access a Confluence page via a Python script to retrieve info I need to parse. My organization added DUO 2FA to the Confluence login. My login attempt returns the standard DUO iFRAME page.

When I login via a browser, this normally sends a PUSH without me having to do anything. My Python request does not seem to do this, though (I get no PUSH).

Here is my test code:

```
import cookielib
import urllib
import urllib2

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'RedditTesting')]
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
payload = {
      'op': 'login-main',
      'os_username': MY_USERNAME,
      'os_password': MY_PASSWORD
}
url = MY_URL
data = urllib.urlencode(payload)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
resp.read()
```

This yields the following (parsed for readability):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Duo Authentication</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>Duo Authentication</h1>

     <div>
       <script src="/download/resources/com.duosecurity.confluence.plugins.duo-twofactor:resources/Duo-Web-v2.js"></script>
       <script>
         Duo.init({ \'host\': OUR_API_SERVER, 
                    \'sig_request\': MY_SIGNED_RESPONSE_CODE,
                    \'post_action\': "\\/plugins\\/servlet\\/duologin?duo.originalurl.key=MY_URL" 
         })
       </script>
       <iframe id="duo_iframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>

   <style>
          #duo_iframe {
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 304px;

      max-width: 620px;
            height: 330px;
          }
        </style>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Am I supposed to be parsing that sig_request value out and sending an /auth API request, or is it supposed to be sending me a PUSH already. Not sure what the normal behavior should be in this case, and all the documentation I can find seems to be for the server side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this mrdrako?

Comment: technically, no, but practically, yes. The org had dedicated AD accounts for RO access that did not require DUO 2FA via API calls.